# Specify jruby ruby version with rbenv

Tags: ruby, version, jruby, rbenv

I'm running OSX mavericks and use `rbenv` to manage my rubies. I want to use `moustache` with my `jruby sinatra` application. `moustache` needs `ruby version 2`, without that I get this error `Gem::InstallError: mustache requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.`

I have this line in my `Gemfile`

```
ruby "2.0.0", :engine => "jruby", :engine_version => "1.7.18"
```

My `jruby ruby` version is `1.9`

```
ruby -v
jruby 1.7.18 (1.9.3p551) 2014-12-22 625381c on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_25-b17 +jit [darwin-x86_64]
```

What is the recommended way for me to get `rbenv` to specify `2.0` as the ruby version?
For now I have set this in my `jrubyrc`

```
cat ~/.jrubyrc
compat.version=2.0
```

But I don't want to have this manual step, I'm sure there must be a way to do this using `rbenv`. I wasn't able to find the right document on google and was wondering if someone here knew.

Comment: No, I encountered more problems with jruby on heroku and eventually settled on vanilla ruby instead.